# Django form raises KeyError in python shell, no error in views

Tags: python, django, shell, exception, django-forms

I have a django form:

```
class ParameterForm(forms.Form):
    pcat = forms.IntegerField()
    gpa = forms.FloatField()
    city = forms.CharField(required = False)
    state = forms.CharField(required = False, min_length = 2, max_length = 2)
```

When I test this form in the python shell I am able to catch missing data as follows:

```
>> parameters = {'pcat' : 70, 'gpa' : 3.5, 'state' : 'TX'}
>> form = ParameterForm(parameters)
>> try:
..     form.data['city']
.. except KeyError:
..     print "No city"
>> No city
```

However when I attempt to utilize this same logic in my view the exception is never raised and the function proceeds until the missing data causes it to break.

from views.py:

```
def sByInfo(request):
    print "\n \n NEW CALL"

    parameter_form = ParameterForm(request.GET)

    if parameter_form.is_valid():


        ranked = Ranked.objects.all()
        unranked = Unranked.objects.all()

        ranked_matches = [] # List for ranked institution matches
        unranked_matches = [] # List for unranked institution matches

        try:
            gpa = parameter_form.data['gpa']
            gpa = float(gpa)
            print gpa
            pcat = parameter_form.data['pcat']
            pcat = int(pcat)
            print pcat

            try:
                city = parameter_form.data['city']
                print city
                state = parameter_form.data['state']
                print state

                position = getPos(city, state)
                lati = Decimal(position['lat'])
                loni = Decimal(position['lon'])

                print "\n RANKED"
                for x in ranked:
                    print x.name
                    average_gpa = (x.gpa_expected + x.gpa_overall) / 2
                    print average_gpa
                    if gpa >= average_gpa:
                        print "GPA good"
                        try: 
                            ranked_matches.index(x)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            ranked_matches.append(x)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "GPA too low"

                    if pcat >= x.min_pcat:
                        try: 
                            ranked_matches.index(x)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            ranked_matches.append(x)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "PCAT too low"

                    lat = Decimal(x.lat)
                    lon = Decimal(x.lon)
                    difference = posDifference(lati, loni, lat, lon)
                    print "Distance is {} miles".format(difference)

                    if difference <= 150:
                        try: 
                            ranked_matches.index(x)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            ranked_matches.append(x)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "School out of range"

                print "\n UNRANKED"
                for y in unranked:
                    print y.name
                    average_gpa = (y.gpa_expected + y.gpa_overall) / 2
                    if gpa >= average_gpa:
                        try: 
                            unranked_matches.index(y)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            unranked_matches.append(y)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "GPA too low"

                    if pcat >= y.min_pcat:
                        try: 
                            unranked_matches.index(y)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            unranked_matches.append(y)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "PCAT too low"

                    lat = Decimal(y.lat)
                    lon = Decimal(y.lon)
                    difference = posDifference(lati, loni, lat, lon)
                    print "Distance is {} miles".format(difference)

                    if difference <= 150:
                        try: 
                            unranked_matches.index(y)
                            print "School already added"
                        except ValueError:
                            unranked_matches.append(y)
                            print "School added"
                    else:
                        print "School out of range"



            except KeyError: ## City or State was not submitted
                print "City or state missing"

                try:
                    state = request.GET['state']

                    for x in ranked:
                        average_gpa = (x.gpa_overall + x.gpa_expected) / 2
                        if gpa >= average_gpa:
                            try:
                                ranked_matches.index(x)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                ranked_matches.append(x)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "GPA too low"

                        if pcat >= x.min_pcat:
                            try:
                                ranked_matches.index(x)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                ranked_matches.append(x)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "PCAT too low"

                        if state.lower() == x.state.lower():
                            try:
                                ranked_matches.index(x)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                ranked_matches.append(x)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "School not in state"


                    for y in unranked:
                        average_gpa = (y.gpa_expected + y.gpa_overall) / 2
                        if gpa >= average_gpa:
                            try:
                                unranked_matches.index(y)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                unranked_matches.append(y)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "GPA too low"

                        if pcat >= y.min_pcat:
                            try:
                                unranked_matches.index(y)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                unranked_matches.append(y)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "PCAT too low"

                        if state.lower() == y.state.lower():
                            try:
                                unranked_matches.index(y)
                                print "School already added"
                            except ValueError:
                                unranked_matches.append(y)
                                print "School added"
                        else:
                            print "School out of state"

                except KeyError:
                    print "City and state missing"

        except KeyError:
            return render('You must enter both GPA & PCAT scores')
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'error' : 'PCAT and GPA values are required.', 'form' : parameter_form})

    return render_to_response('results.html', {'ranked_matches' : ranked_matches, 'unranked_matches' : unranked_matches}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I am rather stumped as to why this exception is raised the shell but not in my view? All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any prints in your console?

Comment: Yes, it prints a blank string for city and executes up to the line `position = getPos(city, state)` where it breaks.

Comment: it sounds like city is defined as the empty string.  IE: `city = ''` -- this is why the `print` statement shows an empty line.

Comment: Can you offer any insight as to how you would catch that? Or an alternative route to catch the missing data and adjust the function accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

As shavenwarthog said, it seems that city is an empty string, that's why the Exception is not raised.

If you want to raise an Error if city is empty, you could:

- remove `required=False` in the city of attribute of your form (but I guess this is not what you want)
- test if the string is empty using: `if not form.data['city'] # returns False if string is empty`

Comment: Unfortunately `if not form.data['city']` returns `True`

Comment: What its value? You could use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to know why it is True. An empty string should be falsy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem as follows:

```
if len(parameter_form.data['city']) != 0:
```

Which checks that the length of the `string` is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Django installed ATM so I cant try my hypothesis, but you have to call `form.is_valid()` to fill the `.data` property:

```
>>> parameters = {'pcat' : 70, 'gpa' : 3.5, 'state' : 'TX'}
>>> form = ParameterForm(parameters)
>>> form.is_valid()
>>> form.data['city']
''
```